# How to search the first regex when few occurrences?

Tags: python, regex

I wan't to extract text between the first "Ananas" and the first dot before. The code works when i have only one "Ananas" in the sentence, but not two.

Example with the sentence :
"Hello. I hate Apples. I love Ananas. But Ananas is too expensive"
and the regex :
`.*[.].*?(.*Ananas)`

If the sentence is only "Hello. I hate Apples. I love Ananas.", i extract "I love Ananas"
But with the sentence "Hello. I hate Apples. I love Ananas. But Ananas is too expensive", i extract the second occurrence "But Ananas"

Comment: `^.*?[.]([^.]*?Ananas)`? https://regex101.com/r/mgVszq/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?<=\.)[^.]*?Ananas`

This regex uses a positive lookbehind to assert the presence of a `.` before searching for any non-`.` characters, up to the first occurrence of `Ananas`.

If you also want to capture the `.`, use `\.[^.]*?Ananas` instead.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AVWHRy/2/)

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to escape the dot inside a character class.

Comment: I left the escape character as force of habit - it makes it a bit more easy to read for me, but I don't have the regex experience you do. Do you recommend removing it?

Comment: Best practice is to escape only what must be escaped, to avoid backlash hell and issues like the ones you have when using patterns in JS regexps with `u` modifier.

Comment: Yes because futur readers may think that they have to escape this character even in a character class.